# writing a file in swift

Tags: ios, swift

this is my code in appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions()

```
  var paths : NSArray =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
    var documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0)
    var fileName: String = String(format: "Logger.txt")
    var logFilePath : NSString = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
    freopen(logFilePath, "a+", stderr)
```

the error am getting is cannot convert NSString to UnSafepointer. 
can anyone help me how should i be implementing this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let go of the casting ;-)

All you need to cast is the NSArray to get you the objectAtIndex() method

```
let paths : NSArray =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0)
let fileName = String(format: "Logger.txt")
let logFilePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
freopen(logFilePath, "a+", stderr)
```

Extra bonus: use let instead of var.

EDIT:

A version without NSArray & NSString:

```
let paths =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
let fileName = String(format: "Logger.txt")
let logFilePath = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: documentsDirectory).URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName).absoluteString
freopen(logFilePath, "a+", stderr)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `NSString` from the `logFilePath`:

```
var paths : NSArray =  NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
var documentsDirectory = paths.objectAtIndex(0)
var fileName: String = String(format: "Logger.txt")
var logFilePath = documentsDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
freopen(logFilePath, "a+", stderr)
```

And a more safer way to do this would be like this:

```
let file = "Logger.txt"
let text = "A safer way to do this"

if let directory : NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true).first {
    let path = directory.stringByAppendingPathComponent(file);

    print(path)

    do {
        try text.writeToFile(path, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    }
    catch {
    }
}
```